# How can I balance a cube with a rigidbody in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I am trying to have a cube rotate itself back to its orginal rotaion whenever the palyer bumbs in the cube but I don't want it to snap back instantly, I  am trying to let it balance itself out and make it look jiggly but I do not how how to make it. I tried differnt ways but none of them work. This is my last try and I know that it is just checking one axis and so but I am clueless so can anybody tell me how to do this.

```
if(transform.rotation.z > 10)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, StartRot, TimeCount);
            TimeCount = TimeCount + Time.deltaTime;
            print("Go");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at this [first](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/class-ConfigurableJoint.html), and there are plenty of tutorials like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7iAjq6V5h8) though that one is about a punching bag the concept is similer.